# How to uninstall/remove ubuntu 14.04 from dual boot windows 8

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

I installed ubuntu on a usb and get the option to run either windows 8 or ubuntu @ startup. I just deleted all the files in the install ubuntu folder in the usb and thought that would do the trick but I guess not :/. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

To remove ubuntu from a usb you would reformat the usb (most likely to some format your other OS uses like fat32 for windows). Reformatting can be done using  disk management in windows, by using a tool like gparted on linux (gparted live disk perhaps?) or by running commands to delete the partitions from a linux command line and reformat your flash drive ([link](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-format-usb-drive-in-the-terminal/))

*the link describes how to find, unmount and reformat your drive with:

- df
- umount
- mkfs.vfat (needs sudo)